# Why I get the "(node:7424) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning" message for handled error?

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

I handle the error in  my Promise by `catch`, but in Node.js (v10.11.0) console output I see the message: `(node:7424) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Oops..`.

Why does it happen?

```js
// See browser console, not stack snippet console, to see uncaught error

const p = new Promise((resolve,reject) => { throw new Error('Oops..');});

p.then(()=> console.log('Then'));
p.catch(err => console.log(err.message)); // the error handling

console.log('The end');
```

Also, I get the same result for such variant of `p` initializing:

```
const p = new Promise((resolve,reject) => { reject(new Error('Oops..'));});
```

This is my output:

> The end
>   Oops..
>   (node:7492) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Oops..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whenever you call `.then` (or `.catch`) on an existing Promise, you have a *new* `Promise`. The error results from the Promise chain created by

```
p.then(()=> console.log('Then'));
```

not being caught anywhere.

Either chain the `.catch` onto the `.then`:

```js
const p = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  throw new Error('Oops..');
});

p
  .then(() => console.log('Then'))
  .catch(err => console.log(err.message));

console.log('The end');
```

Note that when constructing a Promise, it's a good idea to always call `reject` explicitly when there's an error, to ensure that the consumer of that Promise can catch problems. For example, in the following code, the `p` will *not* be rejected, and will remain unresolved forever, because the error was thrown asynchronously:

```js
const p = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    throw new Error('Oops..');
  });
})

p
  .then(() => console.log('Then'))
  .catch(err => console.log(err.message))

console.log('The end');
```

Better to call `reject`:

```js
const p = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    reject('Oops..');
  });
})

p
  .then(() => console.log('Then'))
  .catch(err => console.log(err))

console.log('The end');
```